# Converting javascript code to jquery(need help)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is simple. I'm trying to convert this code to jquery for better execution purposes. But I'm not sure about the syntax.

```
function CopyNotes() {
    var DataSet = document.getElementByID('checkid').value; 
    window.clipboardData.setData("TEXT", DataSet);
}
```

Comment: Define "better execution". You can't get faster than what you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can only *convert* the `value` reading of your function to `jQuery` (*what is still javascript*):

```
function CopyNotes() {
    var DataSet = $('#checkid').val();
    window.clipboardData.setData("TEXT", DataSet);
}
```

Comment: there may be a jQuery plugin to handle `clipboardData` in a cross browser fashion - because window.clipboardData is IE specific

Comment: Yes, totally right @JaromandaX. I didn't touched this part, because he said it is working for him. For a wider browser suppert I know `clipboard.js`, what is a standalone script ... https://clipboardjs.com

Comment: standalone beats jquery plugin every time :p

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```js
$("#copy-button").click(function() {
    var DataSet = $('#checkid').val();
    window.clipboardData.setData("TEXT", DataSet);
});
```